# How do I set the zooming speed of the mouse wheel in amChart library?

Tags: performance, zooming, mousewheel, amcharts

I'm having problems using a huge dataset in AmCharts Library.

I would like to adjust the speed of the mouse wheel scroll, depending on the time period that my chart is showing.

I would like something to specify the dateFormat for each period, as follows:

```
dateFormats: [{period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},  
{period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},{period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
{period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},{period:'DD',format:'MMM DD'},
{period:'WW',format:'MMM DD'},{period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
{period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}]
```

Or, just adding a specific percentage of the number of data displayed.